# How to stop two widgets within stack from overlapping each other?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a chat messenger screen which looks like the given screenshot .
As you can see , bottom message is hidden behind the text input area .
The messages are listview , built using streambuilder .
I want the messages above the text input area .
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A82X2.png

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarMain(context),
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            chatMessageList(),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: Container(
                color: Color(0x54ffffff),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14, vertical: 20),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: messageController,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: ' Message!...',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
                              border: InputBorder.none),
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          sendMessage();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(9),
                            height: 40,
                            width: 40,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Color(0x36FFFFFF),
                                    Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
                                  ],
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/send.png')),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is because you are using a `Stack`. Omit the Stack and use a `Column`.

Comment: @quoci yeah initially i tried the same but i was struggling  to put that input text field in the bottom of screen .

Answer (score 0):

Your structure should be something like

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: chatMessageList(),
    ),
    MessageFieldWidget(),
  ],
)
```

This will ensure that your `chatMessageList` will take up all of the space available in the screen and your Message Field will take up only the space that it needs. You don't need to use Positioned or Padding.